# How to destroy a game object with "Don't Destroy On Load" when a new game starts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a point and click game and the camera stores the main values for the player, but when the players wants to start again, they still have the exact same amount of money, is there a way to destory this when it comes to main menu, or is there a better way to start a new game after a pre-exisiting game.

Ive tried to get the scene name and destroy the object when that happens but that didnt work

Comment: For some reason, it says Unity 3d in the tags, and im trying to change that but it wont allow me to for some reason

Comment: Are you saying that you're using main camera as a game object where you store values?

Comment: yes, and i'd like to destory the camera when a new game starts, or have an alternative to starting a new game

Comment: One way that you can start a new game is that you can reload the scene with SceneManager.LoadScene method. This will reset all the values, however, this option may or may not be suitable for you, depending on your needs.

Comment: @rootpanthera the purpose of `DontDestroyOnLoad` is exactly to be not destroyed when a new scene is load .. so this is most probably what OP already does ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general you destroy the object like any other using `Destroy`.

You could use a Singleton pattern and do something like e.g.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Stores the current singleton instance
    private static Player instance;

    // Read-only public access
    public static Player Instance => instance;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // Does another instance already exist?
        if(instance && instance != this)
        {
            // Destroy myself
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise store my reference and make me DontDestroyOnLoad
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Attach this to your player object, the one you need to keep always but destroy it when you enter the main menu.

And then in your main menu you just need a second component which simply destroys the player object if it exists like e.g.

```
public class DestroyPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start ()
    {
        if(Player.Instance) Destroy(Player.Instance.gameObject);
    }
}
```